# Subtract specific rows

Tags: r

I have data that looks the following way:

```
Participant  Round  Total 
1        100     5
1        101     8
1        102     12
1        200     42      
2        100     14 
2        101     71
40       100     32   
40       101     27
40       200     18
```

I want to get a table with the `Total` of last `Round` (200) minus the `Total` of first `Round` (100) ;

For example - for Participant 1 - it is `42 - 5 = 37`.

The final output should look like:

```
Participant  Total 
1         37
2       
40       -14
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck - but now I found a solution (although less elegant than the 2 proposed here); expEnd=exp[exp$Number_round==200,]  expBegin=exp[exp$Number_round==100,]                               Total_new= expEnd$Total - expBegin$Total

Answer (score 12):

With base R

```
aggregate(Total ~ Participant, df[df$Round %in% c(100, 200), ], diff) 
#   Participant Total
# 1           1    37
# 2           2      
# 3          40   -14
```

Or similarly combined with `subset`

```
aggregate(Total ~ Participant, df, subset = Round %in% c(100, 200), diff)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table) ;
setDT(df)[Round %in% c(100, 200), diff(Total), by = Participant]
#    Participant  V1
# 1:           1  37
# 2:          40 -14
```

Or using binary join

```
setkey(setDT(df), Round)
df[.(c(100, 200)), diff(Total), by = Participant]
#    Participant  V1
# 1:           1  37
# 2:          40 -14
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  filter(Round %in% c(100, 200)) %>%
  summarise(Total = diff(Total))
# Source: local data table [2 x 2]
# 
#   Participant Total
# 1           1    37
# 2          40   -14
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your code (which is clever by the way): what does the `Total[c(1L, .N)]` do? I am guessing I can just refer to a column of each SD directly and dont have to type `.SD[ ,Total]` but what does the `c(1L, .N)` do?

Comment: It's just selecting the first and the last value, as they are always `100` and `200` in the provided example.

Comment: this I understood from testing it, am I right that 1L just select the first item (using 1L instead of 1 because integers require less memory than doubles/floats) and .N gives the number of items in the list so this way I can select the last one? so it would be the same as saying `nrow(dt)` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. See `?data.table` it all there (and many more). `dplyr` also has a similar equivalent function called `n()`.

Comment: yeah i read most of it, but keep forgetting stuff, most of the tricks with datatable i seeon stackoverflow I didnt find in the documentation though, thanks alot! learned alot again, ah yeah the dplyr one I also know, I have used .N many times before in the j part of the data.table-expression but didnt know i could use it in the i-part

Comment: *.N is an integer, length 1, containing the number of rows in the group.* from `?data.table`. I've actually used it in the `j`th expression. I think that you can use it in the `i`th expression only in the newest devel version.

Comment: you used it in the i-expression inside the j-expression of the originial data.table, so you split the original data-table by participant and in each resulting .SD(subdata-table) you selected the first and last row using c(1L, .N) inside the i part of that subdata-table; using it inside i works fine in my version (which is not the devel-version) :1.9.4

Comment: This isn't called `i` expression. The `data.table` structure is a s follows `data.table[ i, j , by]`, so there is no `i` within `j` expression.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, Participant) %>%
    filter(row_number()==1 | row_number()==max(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(df = diff(Total)) %>%
    select(Participant, df) %>%
    unique()
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: Participant

  Participant  df
1           1  37
2           2  57
3          40 -14
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Participant Round Total
                 1        100     5
1        101     8
1        102     12 
1        200     42      
2        100     14 
2        101     71
2 200 80
40       100     32   
40       101     27
40       200     18")

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , .(Total = Total[Round == 200] - Total[Round == 100]), by = Participant]
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone loves a bit of sqldf, so if your requirement isn't to use apply then try this:

Firstly some test data:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Participant Round Total
                 1        100     5
1        101     8
1        102     12 
1        200     42      
2        100     14 
2        101     71
2 200 80
40       100     32   
40       101     27
40       200     18")
```

Next use SQL to create 2 columns - one for the 100 round and one for the 200 round and subtract them

```
rolled <- sqldf("
  SELECT tab_a.Participant AS Participant
        ,tab_b.Total_200 - tab_a.Total_100 AS Difference
    FROM (
        SELECT Participant
            ,Total AS Total_100
        FROM df
        WHERE Round = 100
        ) tab_a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Participant
            ,Total AS Total_200
        FROM df
        WHERE Round = 200
        ) tab_b ON (tab_a.Participant = tab_b.Participant)
    ")
```